# Django - Change UserCreationForm - language

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I made a `UserCreationForm` in `views.py` and calling it in my `register.html` file in templates of that app as `{{ form.as_p }}`
It works fine, but I would like to change the lables of `UserCreationForm` to different language- as

```
    <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
```

I would like to change that "Username" to "ユーザー名" Is it possible? What file should I change and how please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [field's label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#label) in the form with the lazy gettext call.

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=_('Username'))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! Should I add that code to `views.py`? Inside my `register` function? It look like this- please see bellow answer

Comment: If it's a built-in Django form, you'll need to subclass it and override it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the main language of the whole project by changing the entry on the **Settings.py** file

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
```

For a list of languages accepted you can check this link:
[List of Languages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/)

Answer (score -1):

```py
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```